# Test that exception will be thrown isn't working

Tags: jestjs

This trivial class is just an example:

```
class SomeClass{
    getTemplateName() {
        throw new Error('foo');
    }
}
```

to try to test that some code threw an exception:

```
describe('dome class', () => {
    test('contains a method that will throw an exception', () => {
        var sc = new SomeClass();
        expect(sc.getTemplateName()).toThrow(new Error('foo'));
    });
});
```

but it is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In Jest, when you test for a case where an error should be thrown, within your `expect()` wrapping of the function under testing you need to provide one additional function wrapping in order for it to work. I.e.

Wrong:

```
expect(functionUnderTesting()).toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage);
```

Right:

```
expect(() => { functionUnderTesting(); }).toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage);
```

It should make the testing run successfully.

Comment: The documentation states: `Note: You must wrap the code in a function, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail.` I agree it's usage is unexpected https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

Comment: It's not really that unexpected, I mean it makes sense why it is necessary. When. running `expect(functionUnderTesting()).toThrow(ErrorTypeOrErrorMessage);` we have to look at the order in which everything is ran in. First, `functionUnderTesting()` is executed, then the return value is passed into `expects(...)`. The issue here is that before Jest even knows anything about throwing an exception, we've already thrown it. An exception in that context will stop execution and fail. When we wrap it in an arrow function, we're not actually executing it yet and Jest can prepare for the exception.

Comment: "Wrong (but most people's logical approach)" - TIL I'm most people, even if I am wrong

Answer (score 11):

[Jest docs say](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror):

> If you want to test that a specific error gets thrown, you can provide an argument to toThrow. The argument can be a string for the error message, a class for the error, or a regex that should match the error.

So you should code it like this:

```
expect(sc.getTemplateName).toThrow('foo');
```

Or:

```
expect(sc.getTemplateName).toThrow(Error);
```

Comment: files with: expect(sc.getTemplateName()).toThrow(Error);

Comment: fail with expect(sc.getTemplateName()).toThrow('message');

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the code: you must pass the function to `expect` without calling it.

Comment: Please complete your answer. with both cases. And, ... could you explain more about syntax? Sorry: I came from others languages, ... I dont really know the difference of "foo.bar", "foo.bar()" and "() => {foo.bar();}"

Comment: What I've done is change a function call: `sc.getTemplateName()`, with a function reference: `sc.getTemplateName`. So I pass the function to `expect`, which will probably call the function with its own `try / catch` wrapper to be able to match the resulting error against what you provided it with in the `toThrow` argument (an error message or an error class). `foo.bar` would be a function reference, `foo.bar()` a function call and `() => {foo.bar();}` a function which includes a function call.

Answer (score 3):

Jest versions under 20.x.x do not support the syntax you are using. This feature is said to be "coming soon".

In the meantime, you can do the following:

- Sync example:

  ```
  try {
    expect(sc.getTemplateName())
  } catch(e) {
    expect(e.message).toBe('foo')
  }
  ```
- Async example:

  ```
  await expect(sc.getTemplateName()).toMatchObject({message: 'foo'})
  ```

Comment: Could you provide a link to where it says this feature is "coming soon?" Thanks!

Comment: Or _which_ syntax wasn't supported, even. The downside of the `try`/`catch` is that if the error _isn't_ thrown, the test still doesn't fail, and adding an await doesn't fix anything.